# Spring JPARepository hangs when doing a query to Postgresql database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have an app that use spring/hibernate/jparepository that connects to a Postgresql 9.3.9 db.
It does a findAll() query that reads an entire table (20 rows...) with few joins.
On a server with a test db filled with test data it works perfectly.
On another server with the production db filled with production data the app hangs after doing the "select" query and starts burning cpu.
If I paste the same query on pgadmin3 it executes on the production db it in 22ms.
So I am thinking about a java/jdbc/hibernate bug, but I am already using latest versions.

How can I debug it?

Java DAO

```
public interface SitesRepository extends JpaRepository<Sites, Integer> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "tutto", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Sites> findAll();
}
```

PU

```
<persistence-unit name="archeologPU">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>    
</persistence-unit>
```

spring context

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="it.giammar.situumlocalizator" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="it.giammar.situumlocalizator" />



    <!--bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> <property 
        name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/archeolog" /> <property 
        name="username" value="postgres" /> <property name="password" value="postgres" 
        /> </bean -->

    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="1000" />
        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <!--prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/archeolog</prop-->
                <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
                <prop key="password">postgres</prop>
                <prop key="databaseName">archeolog</prop>
                <prop key="serverName">localhost</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Query

`DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select sites0_.id as id1_6_0_, coverings2_.id as id1_0_1_, publicacce3_.id as id1_5_2_, typeofsett5_.id as id1_11_3_, iso31662x6_.alpha4code as alpha1_3_4_, sites0_.code as code2_6_0_, sites0_.description as descript3_6_0_, sites0_.detectionTecnique as detectio4_6_0_, sites0_.langCode_alpha4code as langCod15_6_0_, sites0_.lat as lat5_6_0_, sites0_.location as location6_6_0_, sites0_.lon as lon7_6_0_, sites0_.name as name8_6_0_, sites0_.ownershipAndManagement as ownershi9_6_0_, sites0_.period as period10_6_0_, sites0_.periodOfExcavation as periodO11_6_0_, sites0_.priorityValue as priorit12_6_0_, sites0_.publicAccess_id as publicA16_6_0_, sites0_.siteAuthor as siteAut13_6_0_, sites0_.siteURL as siteURL14_6_0_, protection7_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_2__, protection7_.typeOfSiteProtection_code as typeOfSi2_9_2__, protection7_.levels_id as levels_i3_9_2__, coverings2_.areaNumber as areaNumb2_0_1_, coverings2_.coveringArea as covering3_0_1_, coverings2_.coveringAuthor as covering4_0_1_, coverings2_.criticalArea as critical5_0_1_, coverings2_.date as date6_0_1_, coverings2_.item as item7_0_1_, coverings2_.note as note8_0_1_, coverings2_.previousCode as previous9_0_1_, coverings2_.priority as priorit10_0_1_, coverings2_.sites_id as sites_i11_0_1_, coverings2_.typology_id as typolog12_0_1_, coverings2_.wall_id as wall_id13_0_1_, coverings1_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_0__, coverings1_.coverings_id as covering2_7_0__, protection7_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_2__, protection7_.typeOfSiteProtection_code as typeOfSi2_9_2__, protection7_.levels_id as levels_i3_9_2__, publicacce3_.description as descript2_5_2_, protection7_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_2__, protection7_.typeOfSiteProtection_code as typeOfSi2_9_2__, protection7_.levels_id as levels_i3_9_2__, typeofsett5_.description as descript2_11_3_, settlement4_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_1__, settlement4_.settlements_id as settleme2_8_1__, protection7_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_2__, protection7_.typeOfSiteProtection_code as typeOfSi2_9_2__, protection7_.levels_id as levels_i3_9_2__, iso31662x6_.category as category2_3_4_, iso31662x6_.name as name3_3_4_, iso31662x6_.subdivision as subdivis4_3_4_, protection7_.Sites_id as Sites_id1_6_2__, protection7_.typeOfSiteProtection_code as typeOfSi2_9_2__, protection7_.levels_id as levels_i3_9_2__ from Sites sites0_ left outer join Sites_Coverings coverings1_ on sites0_.id=coverings1_.Sites_id left outer join Coverings coverings2_ on coverings1_.coverings_id=coverings2_.id left outer join PublicAccess publicacce3_ on sites0_.publicAccess_id=publicacce3_.id left outer join Sites_TypeOfSettlement settlement4_ on sites0_.id=settlement4_.Sites_id left outer join TypeOfSettlement typeofsett5_ on settlement4_.settlements_id=typeofsett5_.id left outer join Iso31662 iso31662x6_ on sites0_.langCode_alpha4code=iso31662x6_.alpha4code left outer join Sites_protections protection7_ on sites0_.id=protection7_.Sites_id`

Finally if you wait enough also junit test gives out of memory error (please note that there are 22 rows in the table):

> 10:38:31.960 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager -
>   Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as
>   rollback-only 10:38:31.961 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Setting JPA transaction on
>   EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@745e6f01]
>   rollback-only 10:38:31.961 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
>   10:38:31.961 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling
>   back JPA transaction on EntityManager
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@745e6f01] 10:38:31.962
>   [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
>   10:38:31.962 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - rolled JDBC
>   Connection 10:38:31.962 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction -
>   re-enabling autocommit 10:38:31.985 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@745e6f01] after
>   transaction 10:38:31.986 [main] DEBUG
>   o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
>   10:38:31.988 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing
>   JDBC connection 10:38:31.989 [main] DEBUG
>   o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
>   10:38:31.991 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back
>   transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@379bc1bf testClass =
>   TestPersistence, testInstance =
>   it.giammar.situumlocalizator.TestPersistence@52ccff1e, testMethod =
>   testLeggiSites@TestPersistence, testException =
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space,
>   mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1081350a
>   testClass = TestPersistence, locations =
>   '{file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml}', classes = '{}',
>   contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}',
>   propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}',
>   contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]].

Comment: We have no idea what works and what does not work. So update your question with some code.

Comment: Can you please somehow test with the same data(from prod env) on the test server. Also please provide more info like how many rows are there. What kind of mapping you have and etc.

Comment: Ok you are right. I have now the production data in test db and now it hangs also in test db. So the bug is triggered by some data.

Comment: Do you get an out of memory error eventually?

Comment: When I run junit test no (probably I have not waited enough) but when I put the portlet in Liferay I got an out of memory error elaborating resultset

Comment: @mgiammarco it seems that your problem more closely related with the `Site` entity itself. I mean, how many "connection" that the entity`Site` has to another table?